# Does this type of partition have a name?

Tags: nt.number-theory, partitions, co.combinatorics

If this question is dumb please excuse me.

Does this type of partition have a name and if so, what is it?

A sequence of partitions of an integer $\vec{\lambda}_1, \vec{\lambda}_2,....\vec{\lambda}_j $ such that the tuple of weights $(|\vec{\lambda}_1|,|\vec{\lambda}_2|,.... |\vec{\lambda}_j|)$ forms a partition of a fixed integer $n.$

Comment: You might be thinking of plane partition. See my blog post http://aquazorcarson.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/plane-partitions-lozenge-tiling-and-macmahons-formula/

Comment: This doesn't seem like a plane partition; for example, $\lambda_1 = (1,1,1), \lambda_2 = (2)$ would satisfy his definition, but it isn't a plane partition...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are counted in [OEIS A001970](http://oeis.org/A001970) where they are called "partitions of partitions" along with some other interpretations.  As Simon noted, they do differ from the more-studied plane partitions.